# When run spring boot tests got hazelcast.core.DuplicateInstanceNameException

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, hazelcast

How to execute integration tests of spring boot application with using Hazelcast, because when run all tests got hazelcast.core.DuplicateInstanceNameException?

I use Spring Boot **2.0.0.RC1** and Hazelcast **3.9.2**

Use java configuration for hazelcast:

```
@Bean
public Config getHazelCastServerConfig() {
    final Config config = new Config();
    config.setInstanceName(hzInstance);
    config.getGroupConfig().setName(hzGroupName).setPassword(hzGroupPassword);

    final ManagementCenterConfig managementCenterConfig = config.getManagementCenterConfig();
    managementCenterConfig.setEnabled(true);
    managementCenterConfig.setUrl(mancenter);

    final MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
    mapConfig.setName(mapName);
    mapConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.NONE);
    mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(0);
    mapConfig.setMaxIdleSeconds(0);

    config.getScheduledExecutorConfig(scheduler)
            .setPoolSize(16)
            .setCapacity(100)
            .setDurability(1);

    final NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
    networkConfig.setPort(5701);
    networkConfig.setPortAutoIncrement(true).setPortCount(30);

    final JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
    joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    joinConfig.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);

    final TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig();
    tcpIpConfig.addMember(memberOne)
            .addMember(memberTwo);
    tcpIpConfig.setEnabled(true);

    return config;
}

@Bean
public HazelcastInstance getHazelCastServerInstance() {
    final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(getHazelCastServerConfig());
    hazelcastInstance.getClientService().addClientListener(new ClientListener() {
        @Override
        public void clientConnected(Client client) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Connected %s %s %s", client.getClientType(), client.getUuid(), client.getSocketAddress()));
            log.info(String.format("Connected %s %s %s", client.getClientType(), client.getUuid(), client.getSocketAddress()));
        }

        @Override
        public void clientDisconnected(Client client) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Disconnected %s %s %s", client.getClientType(), client.getUuid(), client.getSocketAddress()));
            log.info(String.format("Disconnected %s %s %s", client.getClientType(), client.getUuid(), client.getSocketAddress()));
        }
    });

    return hazelcastInstance;
}
```

I have simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = UpaSdcApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
 public class CheckEndpoints {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

private static final String HEALTH_ENDPOINT = "/actuator/health";

private static WebTestClient testClient;

@Before
public void init() {
    testClient = org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient
            .bindToApplicationContext(context)
            .configureClient()
            .filter(basicAuthentication())
            .build();
}

@Test
public void testHealth(){
    testClient.get().uri(HEALTH_ENDPOINT).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .json("{\"status\": \"UP\"}");
}
}
```

If run with test class separate from other tests - it execute fine and passes.
If run wiith other tests - get exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'getHazelCastServerInstance' threw exception; nested exception is com.hazelcast.core.DuplicateInstanceNameException: HazelcastInstance with name 'counter-instance' already exists!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.DuplicateInstanceNameException: HazelcastInstance with name 'counter-instance' already exists!
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:124)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at net.kyivstar.upa.sdc.config.HazelcastConfiguration.getHazelCastServerInstance(HazelcastConfiguration.java:84)
    at net.kyivstar.upa.sdc.config.HazelcastConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7da65f3.CGLIB$getHazelCastServerInstance$0(<generated>)
    at net.kyivstar.upa.sdc.config.HazelcastConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7da65f3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b920d5ef.invoke(<generated>)
```

How do you solve this problem? How do you run integration tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceName` configuration element is used to create a named Hazelcast member and should be unique for each Hazelcast instance in a JVM. In your case, either you should set a different instance name for each `HazelcastInstance` bean creation in the same JVM, or you can totally remove `instanceName` configuration if you don't recall instances by using instance name.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it checking if the instance already exists or not:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    HazelcastInstance existingInstance = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName(CACHE_INSTANCE_NAME);
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = null != existingInstance 
         ? existingInstance                                                                       
         : Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelCastConfig());
    return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
}
```

You can see the rest of the code [here](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/pizza-service/src/main/java/com/pizza/configuration/cache/CacheConfiguration.java).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue while running my tests. In my case reason was,that spring test framework was trying to launch new context, while keeping old one cached - thus trying to create another hazelcast instance with the same name, while one was already in the cached context.

> Once the TestContext framework loads an ApplicationContext (or
>   WebApplicationContext) for a test, that context is cached and reused
>   for all subsequent tests that declare the same unique context
>   configuration within the same test suite.

Read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) to understand more about how spring test framework manages test context. 
I am working at the solution at the moment, will post it later. One possible solution I can see is droping test context after each test with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`, but this is very expensive in terms of performance.